# How to realize dynamic chained menu in php and jQuery/ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to realize the function similar to the website: [site](http://visualjquery.com/). I know it's done with jQuery. But can someone guide me with more details?

Thanks very much.

Edit:

The function i need is the chained menu and a result set on the right side. I want the chained menu to be generated automatically from mysql.

Comment: The chained menus and the result set on the right side.

Comment: Retitle your question with a more descriptive title, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to realize this function in php?

The site you mentioned uses jquery to perform its tasks. If you are looking to build a similar site, then you will also have to use jquery or some other ajax framework, you can't do it with pure php unless you use [xajax](http://xajaxproject.org/) which is the ajax framework for php.

Comment: @thanks, i want an analysis for the technologies used in the site. Because i'm totally lost in realizing it. Can you give me some directions?

Comment: yes it uses jquery only, also for any site, you can know what technologies are used by it by downloading the "wappalyzer" addon of firefox and for each site, it will show techs on bottom right corner of firefox. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source of the page to see how it's done.
I doubt that the server side part of this website is hard.

Comment: @thanks Niels, I have seen the source code in the page. But it seems so difficult for me to understand.

Comment: If you're not good at jQuery, read a tutorial/book first, same goes for other techniques (PHP, MySQL).